# Convert Object to Class Type

Tags: java, class, casting

I have Class type returned by one function and want to cast my object to that type. Below is the code:

```
Object valueData; //This is holding some data as Object
Class className = getClassFromFunction(); //className = MyValueClass

//Object val = (className.getClass()) valueData;
boolean validate = validate(valueData); //Failing
```

Here validate function is not accepting the parameter as Object, it will accept as type of the class (className)

```
boolean validate(MyValueClass req){
}
```

How do I cast Object to MyValueClass?

Comment: `(MyValueClass) valueData` ?

Comment: Alternatively `className.cast(valueDate)`.

Comment: Just like any other cast: `MyValueClass req = (MyValueClass) valueData;`

Comment: @vincrichaud actually my className will differ for every request, so I cant cast it directly to (MyValueClass)

Comment: @usr_11 why not?

Comment: that is because at Class className , className will sometimes hold MyValueClass while sometime it will hold MyOtherValueClass.  getClassFromFunction() will return different types of classes.

Comment: @usr_11 if your `validate` method requires a `MyValueClass` as the type of its argument, you must cast the argument to `MyValueClass`. Period.

Comment: Is it working to do something like `className.getClass().cast(valueData)` ?

Comment: when you say `validate`function only accept parameter of type `className`, do you mean there are multiple implementations? ex: `boolean validate(MyValueClass req){}  boolean validate(MyOtherClass req){} ...`

Comment: @usr_11 BTW, `className.cast(valueData)` will not help because `className` of type `Class` and not of type `Class<MyValueClass>` or `Class<? extends MyValueClass>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to understand that casts and deciding which overloaded method to chose ... happens at **compile** time. In contrast to polymorphism, *overloading* is decided at compile time.

Therefore, given a fixed, known sets of "target" classes, the following cascading of `instanceof`, as ugly as it looks, would work out:

```
if (someObject instanceof A) {
  foo((A) someObject);
  return;
} 
if (someObject instanceof B) {
  foo((B) someObject);
  return;
}
```

Please note: there is no "working around" here using reflection. Reflection kicks in at **runtime**, and as said, you need all the information at *compile* time.

If at all, you would have to step back, and see if there are ways of turning your *overloading* approach into polymorphism.